# Multiple threads causing more CPU usage

Tags: c, linux

For the code below my cpu usage is 97%.  I am running c code on Ubuntu.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
void *s_thread(void *x)
{
        printf("I am in first thread\n");
} 
void *f_thread(void *x)    
{
        printf("I am in second thread\n");
}

int main()
{
        printf("I am in main\n");
        pthread_t fth;
        int ret;
        ret = pthread_create( &fth,NULL,f_thread,NULL);
        ret = pthread_create( &sth,NULL,s_thread,NULL); 
        while(1);
        return 0;
}
```

This simple code is giving me more cpu usage than running only one thread.

Comment: Can you please post also the single-threaded version you tried.

Comment: I'm confused. You coded an infinite loop `while(1);` and then .. wonder why it takes only 97% of the CPU? Your threads are dead by the time you get to the infinite loop, where would they .. help? I'm confused what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: this is simple example i am figuring out  but suppose my thread also contain an infinte loop...

Comment: If the `while(1)` is intended to block the main thread you should replace it with something lighter that doesn't claim the cpu as much. This will make your measurements more accurate.

Comment: What is your question, what do you want to achieve? Your code is so far from being reasonable that it is hard to guess, even for the compiler :)

Answer (score 6):

```
int main()
{
    printf("I am in main\n");

    pthread_t fth,sth;
    int ret;

    ret = pthread_create( &fth,NULL,f_thread,NULL);
    ret = pthread_create( &sth,NULL,s_thread,NULL); 

    pthread_join(&fth,NULL);
    pthread_join(&sth,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

`while(1)` uses more CPU cycles, so use `pthread_join` and join the process so that `main` thread waits for child threads to complete.

Comment: thank u, i want that my process will running continously in that case i have to use infinte while loop

Answer (score 4):

In linux there are 3 threads :

- 1 - main thread in which your main() is executing
- 2 - f_thread
- 3 - s_thread

The main thread waits on a while(1) loop, which is causing heavy resource usage. 
You should not use while(1), instead use `pthread_join` (http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_join/) .

With `pthread_join`, your main thread will sleep until other two threads are finished. Thus there won't be unnecessary resource usage.

Comment: thank u, i want that my process will running continously in that case i have to use infinte while loop

Comment: Do your work in main thread, before calling pthread_join. As long as work is in progress, main thread is not reaching the call pthread_join . Somehow if your work in main thread is finished, it should wait on pthread_join (if the two threads f_thread & s_thread are not yet finished).

Comment: It also depends on what work are you doing. if you are using blocking calls , while (1) is okay. For example while(1) {read(....)} . Here the main thread wont take resources since it will be scheduled out when it get blocked on read. When there is data to read, it is scheduled back. Just plain while(1) will hog your CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Put a sleep command into your loop.  For example, the following "sleep" command sleeps for one second:

```
while(1) {
  sleep(1);
}
```

There are other commands that sleep for less time, such as "usleep" provided by unistd.h, which sleeps for a given number of microseconds:

```
while(1) {
  usleep(1000);
}
```